# get value of 4 input type hidden in jquery

Tags: jquery, input, hidden

I have some text boxes with hidden type and it is created at run time and I don't know how many input tags would be created so how can I get each value of this tags while I select a value in select tag on change Event

```
 foreach (var item in (List<NewMVCWebApp.Models.Product>)Session["Cart"])
            {
                <tr id="tr1">
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <h3>@item.name</h3>
                            <figure><img src="~/temp/@item.img" alt="Placeholder" width="232" height="167" name="Img"></figure>
                            <p><span class="rating-d a">4/5</span> 12 Review (s)</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li name="Pcode"><span>@NewMVCWebApp.Resources.HomeTest.Product @NewMVCWebApp.Resources.HomeTest.Code<span>:</span></span> @item.code</li>
                                <li name="Psize"><span>@NewMVCWebApp.Resources.HomeTest.Product @NewMVCWebApp.Resources.HomeTest.Size<span>:</span></span> @item.width * @item.width</li>
                                <li name="Pcolor"><span>@NewMVCWebApp.Resources.HomeTest.Product @NewMVCWebApp.Resources.HomeTest.Colour<span>:</span></span>@item.color</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="se1" class="mySelect" onchange="f22(this)">
                            <option value="@item.price">1</option>
                            <option value="@item.price">2</option>
                            <option value="@item.price">3</option>
                            <option value="@item.price">4</option>
                            <option value="@item.price">5</option>
                        </select>
                        <a id="del1" onclick="javascript: return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Item?')" class="icon-a" href="/Cart/DeleteConfirmed?ID=@item.ID">@NewMVCWebApp.Resources.HomeTest.Delete</a>
                    </td>
                    <td name="Uprice">$@item.price</td>
                    <td id="td1">
                        $<span id="span1" style="width:40px">@item.price</span>
                        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="@item.price" id="@item.ID" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [.each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Something like this should get you started

```
$("input[type='hidden']").each(function() {
    //do whatever you want to here
});
```

Full example

```js
$("input[type='hidden']").each(function(index) {
    console.log("Index: " + index + "\t Val: " + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="1" id="txt1" /> <!-- will get logged -->
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="2" id="txt2" /> <!-- will get logged -->
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="3" id="txt3" /> <!-- will get logged -->
<input name="name" value="4" id="txt4" /> <!-- won't get logged -->
```